# I'm trying to put a CSS&Javascript button to do the job of another label&input checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Essentially, I'm trying to combine two online tutorials:

1st is from the good folks here http://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/ which gives me a button that creates a drop down menu that displays hides with css display attribute, which I have working:

```
 <!-- Load Drop down menu @maxwidth 760px -->
         <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">                                
<!-- END Drop down menu -->
```

I have this working, hiding and showing my

```
<ul id="menu">
```

but I want the below menu button to do the same job. The second is from a great tut for a menu icon that changes to a cross and back again with css and javascript:
http://callmenick.com/post/animating-css-only-hamburger-menu-icons

```
<div class="o-grid__item">
<button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx" >                  
<span>Toggle</span>
</button>
</div>
```

I tried putting on inside the other, but it seemed to lose the functionality… Any help much appreciated.

– – -

OK the full markup is:

```
 <!-- Load Drop down menu @maxwidth 760px -->
 <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">                                
<!-- END Drop down menu -->

                     <!-- START Hamburger Icon -->
                            <div class="o-grid__item">
                            <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx" >                  
                            <span>Toggle</span>
                            </button>
                            </div>
                    <!-- END Hamburger Icon -->                                    

    <!-- END Button for menu below when below CSS Mediaquery -->

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a class="item1" href="/item1.html">item1</a></li>
            <li><a class="item2" href="/item2.html">item2</a></li>
            <li><a class="item3" href="/item3.html">item3</a></li>
        </ul>
```

The second part also has the following Javascript:

```
    <script>
  (function() {

    "use strict";

    var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

    for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var toggle = toggles[i];
      toggleHandler(toggle);
    };

    function toggleHandler(toggle) {
      toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");
      });
    }

  })();
</script>
```

and the following is the css used for the css checkbox:

```
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: inline-block;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
        right: 0px;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        padding-right: 20px
    }

    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        text-align: right;
        line-height: normal;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    }

    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }

    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        padding-right: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        right: 0px;
        top: 10px;
    }

}
```

and the following is the css used for the css/javascript button animation:

```
.c-hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
          transition: background 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.c-hamburger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.c-hamburger span::before {
  top: -10px;
}

.c-hamburger span::after {
  bottom: -10px;
}



.c-hamburger--htx {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span {
  -webkit-transition: background 0s 0.3s;
          transition: background 0s 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
          transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before {
  -webkit-transition-property: top, -webkit-transform;
          transition-property: top, transform;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  -webkit-transition-property: bottom, -webkit-transform;
          transition-property: bottom, transform;
}

/* active state, i.e. menu open */
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active {
  background-color:;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span {
  background: none;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you should have missed the parent-child relationship. Can you please post the full one?

Comment: Cool have added everything I think is relevant to the elements I'm using. Essentially I think I want the button with the class
'c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx' to do what the checkbox with the class 'show-menu' to do… thank for your help, I'm pretty new to this : /

Comment: Can you make a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: I've had a go… http://jsbin.com/ligimukoha/edit?html,css,js,output is that what you'd need…? sorry, only just started with HTML and CSS and don't understand js at all yet…, thanks again

Comment: Sorry buddy, doesn't look like it works for me. Trying my best.

Comment: Cool, well thanks for looking at for me anyway, really appreciated.
It's all below 760px browser width, and I figured I could just put the whole button in the show-menu label…